# Show title only once inside django if statement

Tags: html, django, django-templates, django-views

I have an car object in django view as follows:

```
'damages': [
        {
            "location": "Voorbumper",
            "type": "Kras(10 cm, leger)",
            "severity": "Light damage",
            'comment': "This is some comment.",
            "images": [
                'http://pathtophoto.jpg',
                'http://pathtophoto.jpg'
            ]
        },
        {
            "location": "Vleugel rechts voor",
            "type": "Deuk (Licht)",
            "severity": "",
            'comment': "",
            "images": [
                'http://pathtophoto.jpg',
                'http://pathtophoto.jpg',
                'http://pathtophoto.jpg'
            ]
        },
        {
            "location": "Deur links voor",
            "type": "Kras (5 cm, leger)",
            "severity": "",
            'comment': "",
            "images": [
                'http://pathtophoto.jpg'
            ]
        },
        {
            "location": "Waterlijst",
            "type": "Beschadigd",
            "severity": "",
            'comment': "",
            "images": []
        },
        {
            "location": "Antenne",
            "type": "Ontbreekt",
            "severity": "",
            'comment': "",
            "images": [
                'http://pathtophoto.jpg'
            ]
        },
        {
            "location": "Antenne",
            "type": "Ontbreekt",
            "severity": "",
            'comment': "",
            "images": []
        }
 ]
```

I want to loop through that object and show the images of the damages. But I want first to show the damages with images, and the the damages without images with appropriate title.

In a django template I try to d it as follows:

```
{% for damage in car.damages %}

    {% if damage.images|length > 0 %}

        <div class="width-100 pad text-left primary-bg">{% trans "Shades met foto's" %}</div>

        <div class="width-100 mar-top clear-float">
            <div class="width-30 bord-my-way pad-half damage-info">
                <div class="mar-btm-half"><b>{{ damage.location }}</b></div>
                <div class="mar-btm-half">{{ damage.type }}</div>
                <div class="mar-btm-half">{{ damage.severity }}</div>
                <div class="mar-btm-half">{{ damage.comment }}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="width-70 pad-lft damage-photos">
                {% for image in damage.images|slice:"3" %}
                    <div class="width-33 pad-rgh">
                        <img src="{{ image }}" class="width-100"/>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <div class="clear-float"></div>
            {% if forloop.counter == 7 or forloop.counter == 14 or forloop.counter == 21 %}
                <p style="page-break-before: always"></p> {% endif %}

        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% for damage in car.damages %}

    {% if damage.images|length == 0 %}
        <div class="width-100 pad text-left primary-bg mar-top">{% trans "Shades zonder foto's" %}</div>
        <div class="green-bg">{{ damage.location }}</div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Thus, I first loop through damages where `damage.images|length > 0` and then in the second for I check if there is no images with `damage.images|length == 0`. But the title is shown for every `for loop`iteration.

I could place the title's for the `for loop`. Something like:

```
<div> Damages with photos </div>
{% for damage in car.damages %}
   {% if damage.images|length > 0 %}
      // Show it
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %
```

And

```
<div> Damages without photos </div>
{% for damage in car.damages %}
   {% if damage.images|length == 0 %}
      // Show it
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %
```

But sometimes I have only damages with images or only damages without images and then I see the title although I do not have any damages to show.

Is there any way to do something only once inside the `if statement`, something like:

```
{% for damage in car.damages %}
       {% if damage.images|length > 0 %}
          <div>Damages with the photos</div> // Show it only once when it comes here
          // Show the damages with photos
       {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% for damage in car.damages %}
       {% if damage.images|length == 0 %}
          <div>Damages without the photos</div> // Show it only once when it comes here
          // Show the damages without photos
       {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not overly familiar with Django and Python anymore, but I guess you could do a preliminary check to see if there are damages with or without images in there.

```
damages_with_images = [d for d in damages if d.images.length > 0]
damages_without_images  = [d for d in damages if d.images.length == 0]
```

And then just loop over these two separate arrays, and only print the heading if they are not empty...

```
{% if damages_with_images|length > 0 %}
  put heading1
{% endif %}
# ... loop ...

{% if damages_without_images|length > 0 %}
  put heading2
{% endif %}
# ... loop ...
```

Of course this has worse performance because of multiple loops.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do in your position is

1. Either pass two separate `QuerySet`s in the template, the first would include damages with images and the other damages without images.
2. Leave the `QuerySet` as is and create two custom template filters that would do the same job as the step #1 above.

Case 1:

```
# views.py

def my_view(request):
    damages_w_img = Damage.objects.filter(images__isnull=False)
    damages_wo_img = Damage.objects.filter(images__isnull=True)
    return render(request, 'template.html', locals())


<!-- template.html -->

{% if damages_w_img.exists %}
    <h1>This list of damages contains images</h1>
    {% for damage in damages_w_img %}
        do stuff here, each damage has an image
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

{% if damages_wo_img.exists %}
    <h1>This list of damages does not contain images</h1>
    {% for damage in damages_wo_img %}
        do stuff here, each damage does not has an image
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Case 2:

```
# custom_template_filter.py

from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def with_images(damages):
    return damages.objects.filter(images__isnull=False)

@register.filter
def without_images(damages):
    return damages.objects.filter(images__isnull=True)


<!-- template.html -->

{% with damage_w_img=car.damages|with_images damage_wo_img=car.damages|without_images %}

    {% if damages_w_img.exists %}
        <h1>This list of damages contains images</h1>
        {% for damage in damages_w_img %}
            do stuff here, each damage has an image
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if damages_wo_img.exists %}
        <h1>This list of damages does not contain images</h1>
        {% for damage in damages_wo_img %}
            do stuff here, each damage does not has an image
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

{% endwith %}
```